# Remove recessed faucet aerator that lacks notches

Tags: faucet, cleaning

I’ve read several similar posts and answers but I think my faucet may be a bit different. I have a hidden / recessed aerator but there are no notches for any tools to fit to unscrew it. However I’m able to twist the aerator with my fingers but it never seems to get any looser or tighter, it just keeps spinning.

I tried taking a wrench to the faucet spout (first two photos) but nothing budged. Any suggestions for how I could remove the aerator for cleaning would be much appreciated! Photos attached. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The bottom ring( the one with the stains) shown in the first picture, probably unscrews.

Try dipping the end in some vinegar for a few minutes first.

Would try by wrapping cloth or rubber around it and using pliers/small pipe wrench to unscrew.

Comment: I tried taking a wrench to that part last night and it didn’t budge. After leaving it in cleaning vinegar overnight it worked! You were right, that part did unscrew. Many thanks!!